# 2 CSS background override each other

Tags: css

```css
body{
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Lake_macquarie_dusk.JPG);
  background-size:cover;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#search{
  color:white;
  font-size:200px;
}
#search:hover{
  background:white;
  height:260px;
  width:260px;
  border-radius:50%;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
#search:hover{
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Lake_macquarie_dusk.JPG) fixed no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<div id='search'><i class="fa fa-search circle"></i></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

For #seach, I have two backgrounds for its hover effect. One of the background properties is to clip the background picture to the magnifying glass. The other background is for the white circle.

Here is the effect I want. But IMPORTANT: notice the hover effect are clipped to 2 different things. One hover effect is clipped to the outter div. The other hover effect is clipped to the magnifying glass. So if you move your cursor just little bit out of the magnifying glass will just disappear, leaving only the circle.

Here I change #search, which belongs to the outter div, to .circle, which belongs to the  tag.

```css
body{
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Lake_macquarie_dusk.JPG);
  background-size:cover;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#search{
  color:white;
  font-size:200px;
}
#search:hover{
  background:white;
  height:260px;
  width:260px;
  border-radius:50%;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.circle:hover{
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Lake_macquarie_dusk.JPG) fixed no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<div id='search'><i class="fa fa-search circle"></i></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what the nature of the problem is and what the desired result is

Comment: In CSS, the last applied property takes precedence. If you imagine every property in your file is on one line, the right-most one will be what you see on the webpage. If multiple CSS files are involved, the last one that is parsed will cause it. This is probably not what you are looking for, but it will help you debug it.

Comment: Properties are also inherited from parent blocks, so if you remove a property, it may still be applied if it comes from a parent. You will need to neutralize it.

Comment: @A.Williams. The second one is the desired result. But the hover effect isn't clipped to the same thing. You can try moving your mouse out of the magnifying glass but inside the circle. See what happen.